# Should I install npm in Kubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, npm

I am using Kubuntu. I am looking into installing a plugin to help in javascript. This seems to be good [jshint](http://www.jshint.com/install/) but it mention `npm install`
What is this? My understanding is that in Kubuntu I should only use `sudo apt-get` to install packages and not `yum` or anything else. What is this `npm`? Should I use it or will I have conflict issues with my package manager?

Comment: What is your goal here? From the tags you used it seems you are just looking to use it as an editor plugin for syntax highlighting/error detection. What version of Kubuntu are you running?

Comment: @Seth:You are right. Ubunty 13.10

Answer (score 1):

Npm is a node.js module/package manager. It can work without root privileges, installing into your home directory. As a consequence, unless you use `npm install -g` (as root, **globally**), there won't be any conflicts with the native package management system.

Comment: What is the difference with `-g`?

Comment: @Jim `-g` installs it globally for all users.

Answer (score 0):

`npm` is node.js package manager. First you need to install npm on your system.

Add repository first

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
```

Then install npm

```
apt-get update
apt-get install npm
```

Then you can install the module with `npm` as the site suggests.

```
npm install jshint
```